What does "that" in "No one ever meant that, Drax" refer to?
Rocket suggests Mantis to make Peter happy using her powers. Groot questions, Nebula is surprised, and Mantis misunderstands Rocket’s suggestion. Rocket clarifies he meant her powers, not physical touch. He states it’s wrong to manipulate friends’ feelings. Drax brings up a past incident where Mantis made him fall in love with his sock, which Mantis finds funny:

Drax: I guess it's back to one of us touching him the other way. Maybe we should draw straws.
Nebula: No one ever meant that, Drax.

I'm unsure whether 'that' refers to "draw straws" or "physically touching Peter" in the context.
What does "that" in "meant that" refer to ?

I feel like the joke went over your head :-)

You (and Drax) have both misunderstood.
The line is

"Mantis, why don’t you just touch him and, you know, make him happy?"

Groot responds

"I am Groot?"

to which the other characters say things like "Dude!" and "Gross!", so clearly what he said was inappropriately sexual.
The 'that' in "meant that" is referring to touching Peter's gentleman parts.

That is to say touching Peter's peter.
